# Can XSLT be used to apply CSS styles?

Tags: xslt, adobe-indesign

I have some XML and a very small XSLT to convert that into HTML. When I import my XML content in InDesign using the XSLT, I can see the styles are applied to the elements on the left hand browsing side but, when I drag and drop the elements in the InDesign frames, nothing is happening. The content is flowing normally.

My question is, in InDesign, is XSLT getting used only for sequencing the elements or can we use XSLT to apply the styles (like `font-size`, `line-spacing` etc.) as well for elements?

Also, if you can send me any sample XSLT for converting an XML to HTML tags or any example, that will be great.

Answer (score 2):

In general, formatting in InDesign has nothing in common with CSS styles -- that is a HTML construction, not an XML one. You can indeed only reorder elements (and other element-wise stuff, such as removing, replacing, or adding tags).

Formatting can be applied to the tags *after* you imported/translated your XML using Map Styles To Tags (or Map Tags to Styles; I don't think I've ever used either).

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML within XLST so, if you have something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="node"/>
```

Then this can also be written like:

```
<div class='style'><xsl:value-of select="node"/></div>
```

Or you can use inline CSS like:

```
<div style='color:red;'><xsl:value-of select="node"/></div>
```

Hope this helps!